# Permission denied in ie9 when handling jquery event

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, iframe

I have permission denied error in i9,ie8 when i return from event handler. In other browsers(firefox, chrome) all works fine. Error in jquery 1.8.1:

```
nodeName: function( elem, name ) {
    return elem.nodeName && elem.nodeName.toLowerCase() === name.toLowerCase();
},
```

I bind click in iframe like this

```
 var bindClicks = function (iframe, events) {
    $.each(events, function (key, value) {
        iframe.contents().find(key).click(value);
    });
};
```

using like that:`bindClicks(iframe, {
                '#showDetails':onShowTechnicalDetails
            });`

```
var onShowTechnicalDetails = function (e) {
    alert('Error after end this');
};
```

All other handlers in this style are working properly, except this. What can be wrong?

FIXED:
I do not know if this will help someone, the problem was that the element to which I was hanging event was link `<a href ='#'> text </a> i change it to <a href='javascript:void(0)'> text </a> and it work!`

Comment: i don't have much knowledge where iframes are concerned but are there not (differing) security constraints on them and especially on javascript dom manipulation unless the script is in the iframe content? could be wrong about that, pinch of salt etc.

Comment: Very strange is that only the handler causes an error. i try many ways but it seems something breaks down in jquery. but how it could be=)

Comment: You can answer the question yourself and accept the answer if you have found the solution

Comment: i dont have enougth reputation they said =) In any case, it is not important, the main thing now it works!